# rsync replace only matching files with hardlinks

Tags: linux, rsync, deduplication

How to replace files in `dst/`, that exactly matches by content with files from `src/` with hardlinks to these (`src/*`) files?

There is `--hard-links` option for `rsync`, which I want to use, but I don't want to touch changed files, just to minimize the amount of disk space wasted. Is it possible to acheive with `rsync`?

I mean, that `rsync` is used in non-`--recursive` mode, but in `--non-inc-recursive` mode, to make global-wide comparison of the contents.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a program like `fslint`, `fdupes`, `duff`, `rdfind` to find duplicates, then free the duplicated disk space with links.

You could take the list of duplicates from one of those utilities and create your own links & rm'ing files, or...

`rdfind` has this option that sounds like just what you're looking for:

```
-makehardlinks true|false
          Replace duplicate files with hard links
```

---

And definitely have a good backup first, and look for "dry run/simulate" options (like rdfind's "-n -dryrun")

Comment: Is this possible to achieve with `rsync`? It'll be universal tool in the case.

Comment: I think rsync's more specialized in *creating* duplicates, not finding & deleting them. A single universal tool idea is kind of counter to the old Linux/Unix idea of "do one thing, and do it well"... `rdfind` should be in the standard repos of Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora, I think the other tools should be too, so generally universally available?